# IntelliJ Kubernetes View not show any cluster information

Tags: intellij-idea

Kubernetes View not working, only show path to cert for active context and message in the toolbar that indicate unknown cluster

[image]

I tried set path to config file, but without successful

[image]

LOGS:

```
2020-01-07 12:07:53,303 [15549238]   WARN - lij.kubernetes.model.ModelData - Unable to read OpenAPI specification from C:\Users\ondra\.kube\config\admin.conf 
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:865)
```

But that config file is originaly generated from Kubernetes

Comment: Is there anything relevant in idea.log (Help | Show log...)? You can try to get additional logging by adding #com.intellij.kubernetes  in Help | Debug Log Settings.

Comment: @PetrRastegaev I added snippet

Answer (score 0):

I found problem. Kubernetes admin.conf file have relative paths to certs (e.g. ..\certs...) I changed to absolute path and it showed informations, but apears unauthorized

[image]